# What is the meaning of "get a hold of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "I'm trying to get a hold of Mrs Who?" mean?

Comment: Search *get hold of* as a phrase. If still in doubt, you can ask on [ell.se]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs on ELL.

Comment: I guess you could have found it in a dictionary maybe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means you are trying to find the person in question, or trying to get in contact. It's idiomatic - you're not actually trying to physically get a hold of them.

Answer (score 1):

## get hold of

1. To come into possession of; find: Where can I get hold of a copy?
2. To communicate with, as by telephone: tried to get hold of you but the line was busy.
3. To gain control of. Often used reflexively: You must get hold of yourself!

The first one refers to the meaning of your sentence

It simply means **to communicate with someone** as ElendilTheTall said..